# How to change the tabs in another window Titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator

Inside my application i have a login screen WHERE i have 2 tabs , after the login i open another window 
i want to change the tabs in that window {remove those 2 from the previous window and add 4 new tabs } 
How can i do it in Titanium ?

Answer (score 1):

There is an example of how to do this in the KitchenSink Titanium demo application.  It you go to *Base UI > Tab Groups*, you will see an "*Add/Remove Tab*" button, which does what you want I think.  You can find the code for that file here:

https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/examples/tab_groups.js

The code itself for adding and removing tabs from that file:

```
if (tabGroup.tabs.length == 5)
{
    var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({title:'New Tab Window',barColor:'#000'});
    var newtab = Titanium.UI.createTab({  
        icon:'../images/tabs/KS_nav_mashup.png',
        title:'New Tab',
        win:win
    });
    tabGroup.addTab(newtab);
}
else
{
    var newtab = tabGroup.tabs[5];
    tabGroup.removeTab(newtab);
}
```